# Jquery.ajax request to update a page with a partial template in ruby-on-rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Im trying to use a javascript/Jquery.ajax request to update a page with a partial template in ruby on rails. The partial is called _promotions.html.erbI am a noob with javascript and JQuery and don't understand the syntax well. From the page to be updated:

```
<div id="promotions"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/promotions", // it routes to the following def
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html"
    success: $(function(data){$('#promotions').write(data)})
  });
</script>
```

From the rails controller handling the response:

```
def promotions
  @items = Item.search("", 8) #the partial needs this variable during preprocessing
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :partial => "promotions", :layout => false, }
  end
end
```

I want to render _promotions.html.erb into the page. Eventually I want to be able to it rerender the contents of that div periodically without refreshing the whole page (hence the jquery call rather than via rails preprocessing). Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "/promotions",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "html", // You missed a comma.
  success: function(data){$('#promotions').html(data)}
});
```

There isn't a jQuery `.write()` method.
Also, don't wrap `function(data){$('#promotions').html(data)}` in `$(...)` as you did.

`$('#promotions')` returns the DOM element of id *promotions*, but `$(function() {})` is only used to [bind a function which runs when the document is ready](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3).